# Error con prisma al subir mi aplicacion nodejs a cpanel

Tags: nodejs, cpanel

Cuando intento correr mi aplicacion de nodejs que usa prisma en mi cpanel, me salta el siguiente error:

```
Error: @prisma/client did not initialize yet. Please run "prisma generate" and try to import it again.
In case this error is unexpected for you, please report it in https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues
    at new PrismaClient (/home/sekaijkc/nodevenv/sekaijk-api/16/lib/node_modules/.prisma/client/index.js:3:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/sekaijkc/sekaijk-api/Controllers/AuthoController.js:5:16)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/sekaijkc/sekaijk-api/Router/Authenticator.js:3:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
```

Ya instale prisma y @prisama/client y cuando hago `prisma generate` me salta el siguiente error:

```
/home/usuario/nodevenv/carpeta/16/lib/node_modules/prisma/build/index.js:12352
    var wasmInstance = new WebAssembly.Instance(wasmModule, imports);
                       ^

RangeError: WebAssembly.Instance(): Out of memory: wasm memory
    at ../../node_modules/.pnpm/@prisma+prisma-fmt-wasm@4.5.0-43.0362da9eebca54d94c8ef5edd3b2e90af99ba452/node_modules/@prisma/prisma-fmt-wasm/src/prisma_fmt_build.js (/home/usuario/nodevenv/carpeta/16/lib/node_modules/prisma/build/index.js:12352:24)
    at __require (/home/usuario/nodevenv/carpeta/16/lib/node_modules/prisma/build/index.js:14:50)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/usuario/nodevenv/carpeta/16/lib/node_modules/prisma/build/index.js:86368:38)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
```

Y cuando uso npx prisma generate me salta el mismo error.

mi schema.prisma, en su generator tengo lo siguiente:

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
  binaryTargets = ["linux-musl"]
}
```

y en mi rutas esta como

carpteta
-controles
-rutas
-Model
-prisma
--schema.prisma
...

Entonces no se como terminar de configurarlo o que hacer para correrlo correctamente.

Comment: Para descartar. Hiciste un `npm install` antes de todo?

Comment: Si, en los logs no aparecio un error con respecto, es al momento de arrancar la aplicacion